# C# DBContext Include not finding nested table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Having an issue where I can not include [RelatedTableTwo] when loading data into my EF 6 DBContext object.  I have tried using ThenInclude, but it does not find the tables and errors out.  The code is using EntityFrameWorkCore.  Here is the code:

```
'var MainTable = context.MainTable
                        .Include(i => i.RelatedTableOne)
                             .ThenInclude(ti => ti.RelatedTableTwo)
                             .ThenInclude(ti => ti.RelatedTableThree)
                             .Where(p => p.Id ==id)                                                     
                             .ToList();'
```

[image: Simple Diagram]
[I believe the issue is Related Table Two has a one-to-many relationship to Related Table One which is not allowing the loading of the data from the Context object.] <- This is not the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  When I used the "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" command it created HashSets.  When using the includes, the includes did not recognize Related Table Two.  I changed the HashSet variables to generic list collections and now it works.